# In the proof that an algebraic set $V$ is irreducible iff $I(V)$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $k$ be a field, $\Bbb{A}^n(k)$ be affine $n$-space over $k$, and $R = k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$.

> If $V \subset \Bbb{A}^n(k)$ is algebraic, then it's irreducible iff $I(V)$ is prime.

The proof in the first direction goes:

> If $I(V )$ is not prime, suppose $F_1F_2 ∈ I(V )$, $F_i \notin I(V ), i=1,2$. Then $V = (V \cap V (F_1)) \cup (V \cap V (F_2))$, and $V \cap V (F_i) \subsetneq V$ , so $V$ is reducible.

I'm not seeing how they get that equality involving $V$.  Also, what lemma says we can pick such $F_1, F_2$ to begin with?

---

I know that $V(F_1 F_2) = V(F_1) \cup V(F_2)$.

Comment: That's the definition of a prime ideal. An ideal is not prime means there are two elements who's product is in the ideal, but they themselves are not.

Comment: The containment $\supseteq$ should be clear. For the other one, given $v \in V$ then $(F_1 F_2)(v) = 0$, so either $F_1(v) = 0$ or $F_2(v) = 0$ and thus $v \in V(F_1)$ or $v \in V(F_2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathcal I(V)$ is not prime, then by definition, there is $F_1,F_2$ both not in $\mathcal I(V)$ such that $F_1F_2\in \mathcal I(V)$. The notation here is confusing. By $\mathcal{V}(F_i)$ they mean the variety of the ideal $(F_1)$, not $V$ times $(F_i)$ (which doesn't even make sense).

I will use $\mathcal V$ for variety. We claim
$$V=(V\cap \mathcal V(F_1))\cup(V\cap \mathcal V(F_2)).$$
Clearly $(V\cap \mathcal V(F_1))\cup(V\cap \mathcal V(F_2))\subseteq V$. On the other hand, any element of $x\in V$ must be a root of either $F_1$ or $F_2$ since $x$ is a root of $F_1F_2$. Thus $x$ is in either $\mathcal V(F_1)$ or $\mathcal V(F_2)$, so $V\subseteq (V\cap \mathcal V(F_1))\cup(V\cap \mathcal V(F_2))$. Thus $V$ is reducible.

Conversely, suppose that $V$ is reducible. Then $V$ is a finite union of irreducible algebraic sets, which we can write as $\mathcal V(J_k)$ for prime ideals $J_k$. Then

$$\mathcal I(V)= \mathcal I\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n\mathcal{V}(J_k)\right) = \bigcap_{k=1}^n\mathcal I(\mathcal V(J_k))=\bigcap_{k=1}^n\sqrt{J_k}=\bigcap_{k=1}^n J_k$$
by the Nullstellensatz. Since these ideals are distinct by definition, $\mathcal I(V)$ is not prime.

Comment: How did you get $I(V) = J\cap K$ for some $J, K$ ideals?  I only get that if $J = I(U)$ for some set $U \subset \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ ie only for an ideal of points, sim $K$.

Comment: You're right; it should be fixed now.

Comment: When we say that $x \in V$ must be a root of either $F_1$ or $F_2$ since $x$ is a root of $F_1 F_2$ we are using the integral domain property of $k$, right?

Comment: Simpler converse proof:  "By contrapositive.  If $V = V_1 \cup V_2,$ with $V_i \subsetneq V$ , then $I(V_i) \supsetneq I(V )$.  Let $F_i \in I(V_i) \setminus I(V), \ i = 1,2$ such that $F_1 F_2 \in I(V)$ and $I(V)$ is not prime."